# Question about pipe function in c source code

Tags: c, pipe, codeblocks

I practice and tried to understand below C source code which is quote from "A book on C" for analyzing pipe function. 
But what I can't understand is pd[0] have to be 3, and pd[1] have to be 4,  whenever I run the Codeblocks' debugger until line 15(`for(i=0;i<N;i++)`).

Is there anyone know why pd[0] should be 3, and pd[1] should be 4,which is different than my expectation?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 3
int add_vector(int v[]);
void error_exit(char *s);
int fork(void);
int pipe(int pd[2]);
int read(int fd,void *buf,unsigned len);
write(int fd,void *buf,unsigned len);
int main()
{
int a[N][N]={{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3,3}},i,row_sum,sum=0,pd[2]={0,0};
if(pipe(pd)==-1)
    error_exit("pipe() failed");
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
if(fork()==0){
    row_sum=add_vector(a[i]);
    if(write(pd[1],&row_sum,sizeof(int))==-1)
        error_exit("write() failed");
    return;
}
    for(i=0;i<N;++i)
    {
        if(read(pd[0],&row_sum,sizeof(int))==-1)
            error_exit("read() failed");
        sum+=row_sum;
    }
    printf("Sum of the array=%d\n",sum);
    return 0;
}

int add_vector(int v[])
{
    int i,vector_sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        vector_sum+=v[i];
    return vector_sum;
}
void error_exit(char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"\nERROR:%s-bye!\n",s);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: They're just the two lowest available descriptors. Have some open files when you call `pipe()`, and you'll get different numbers.

Comment: Standard input is file descriptor 0; standard out is 1; standard error is 2.   The lowest available file descriptors for the pipe are 3 and 4, therefore.  Open another file before calling `pipe()`  BBC and the numbers will change.

Comment: Why do you have prototypes for standard functions like `pipe()` instead of including the appropriate headers?

Comment: Thank you all very much for your reply! As I expected Western programmer has very extensive knowledge for C language and It really help me a lot to understand anything which I doubt but nearly impossible to find any clear anwser in korea website or programming community.And  aforementioned C source code is not written by myself, but I quote from A book on C textbook("interprocess communication using pipes()" 561-562 page)